# WPF Incorrectly Showing the Taskbar After Clicking a Window

Tags: c#, wpf, windows, mvvm

I have a bug with my WPF application. When a user takes an action in the program a "please wait" window is initialized. That window stays active until some information is processed, at which point the "please wait" window goes away.

The problem is that when the "please wait" window is active, the user is able to click the screen and have the task bar show up. The application does not minimize, but the task bar shows up on top of the program until the "please wait" window is disabled, at which point the task bar disappears.

Here are the settings for the "please wait" window;

```
ResizeMode="NoResize" MaxHeight="500" MaxWidth="400" WindowState="Normal" ShowInTaskbar="False" ShowActivated="False"
```

I have another window that appears with more generic warnings, which never has this issue of the task bar appearing when clicking the screen. The settings for that window are;

```
ResizeMode="CanMinimize" MaxHeight="500" MaxWidth="400" WindowState="Normal"
```

I find it most confusing that one window will have the problem, but another window (which is almost a carbon copy of the first, with different buttons) does not.

I am not sure if I have provided enough context and background information about the program and the problem. I imagine more information will be necessary, but I was hoping to at least pinpoint where this problem may be happening - or discuss it with other people if anyone has experience with an issue like this.

Comment: Why would the task bar not normally be visible?  Is there a full-screen application window below these windows?  Are you setting the `Owner` of either of the two windows you described?  Where exactly is the user right-clicking to bring up the task bar?  In one of your windows, on the desktop, or somewhere else?

Comment: The task bar is not normally visible for the reason you assumed, there is a full screen application that is below these windows. The owner is not set for either window. The user is able to left click on the "please wait" window, which causes the task bar to show. Thank you for asking for more clarification, hopefully this was of some help.

Comment: If no owner is set, what prevents the user from clicking on the main window in the background and effectively hiding the "please wait" window?  Have you tried using process of elimination to see if any of the properties set on one window but not the other might be responsible?

Comment: Hi Mike. Yes, my effort was first spent trying to compare the two .xaml files and determine if anything was different. Other then the widgets, the two lines above were the only real differences I could find. In regards to ownership, I am not entirely sure. I could not find any explicit setting of ownership for either window and neither window has the functionality that you describe (hiding when clicking behind). I am continuing to look for differences between the two classes, as there must be something that is different between the two to cause the error in one but not the other.

Comment: But did you actually try removing the two different properties to see if that made a difference?  It's not clear from your comment whether you tried removing them or merely observed the differences.

Comment: Ah, yes, sorry. I am picking some of this up from another developer, and the comment was made that those two lines (showInTaskbar and showActivated) were added to prevent the task bar permanently showing anytime that the "please wait" window was active.

Comment: That sounds like a useful clue.  I'd remove the properties and focus on figuring out why the taskbar shows up when one window is activated but not the other.  Also, use Snoop to see for certain whether either window's `Owner` is set after it has been shown.